# A question about rational number.

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, linear-programming

Denote $M$ as a $m\times n$ matrix whose components are all nonnegative integers (actually 0 or 1) and $1$ as the $m$ dimensional vector $(1,1,\cdots,1)$. Show that:

> There is a vector $x_0$ minimize $1^Tx$ such that $Mx \geq 1$ where the components of $x$ are nonnegative, and the components of $x_0$ are all rational numbers.

This question is from a sentence in the bottom of [page 3 of a book](http://www.ams.jhu.edu/~ers/fgt/fgt.pdf),

> We may assume that $x$ is rational (since the data in the LP are all integers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general your theorem doesn't hold, because there is the possibility that $Mx\geq1$ do not upperbound your function $1^Tx $.

Example in $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$-x_1-x_2\geq 1$

There is no vector $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^2$, which minimize your function since your function $x_1+x_2$ always decreases with $x_1$, $x_2$ going into direction $-\infty$.

Such problems like yours are often bounded by additional sign constraints:
$x\geq 0  $

With your function $1^Tx$ and this additional constraint your theorem holds, because $1^Tx$ is upperbounded by $x=0$ and then your optimal point $x_0$ is a corner (or an arbitrary point on a whole facet) of the konvex set $Mx\geq1,\;x\geq0$.

(the minimum $x_0$ is rational, because your matrix M consists of integers and a corner of $Mx\geq1,\; x\geq0$ is a solution of a linear equation system over a subset of the equations $Mx=1, x=0$.)

Comment: I am sorry, it's my fault.

Comment: Happend. You are welcome.. :)

Comment: I'll update the question now

Comment: The reason for $x$ to be rational is the same in the modified case. Your area $Mx\geq1,\;x\geq0$ is konvex and your function $1^Tx$ is upperbounded in this system. Therefore you always get a minimum in a corner (sometimes as a part of the whole facet) of the konvex area and a corner is the solution of a linear equation system over a subset of equations of $Mx=1,\;x=0$. Since M has only integers, the solution $x$ of that linear equation system has to be rational.

Comment: See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Existence_of_optimal_solutions) and apply the conditions to your problem.

Comment: Thanks! You'd better write it down as an answer to end this post.

Comment: Why? It is part of this answer.